# Datatable with twig in symfony 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatable, twig

I'm implementing the js library [Datatable](https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle).

I installed all dependencies like bootstrap Datatables ... through yarn.

This is my app.js file :

```
    import './styles/app.scss';
    
    import 'bootstrap'
    import 'datatables'
    
    import './bootstrap';
    
    import '../public/bundles/datatables/js/datatables'
    
    const table = $('#presidents')
    const setting = table.attr("data-table-setting");
    console.log(setting)
    table.initDataTables( setting, {
        searching: true
    } );
```

As you can see, I'm following example given by the documentation.

This is now How I pass **setting** from twig to app.js (I think the issue come from here...)

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    {% include '_alertFlash.html.twig' %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="presidents" data-table-setting='{{ datatable_settings(datatable) }}'>Loading...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**datatable** obviously come from my controller. This is the code:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\LineOfBusiness;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\Doctrine\ORMAdapter;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\NumberColumn;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_home')]
    public function index(Request $request, DataTableFactory $dataTableFactory): Response
    {
        $table = $dataTableFactory->create()
            ->add("id", NumberColumn::class, ["label" => "Id", "searchable" => true, "globalSearchable" => true])
            ->add("name", TextColumn::class, ["label" => "Name", "searchable" => true, "globalSearchable" => true])
            ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
                'entity' => LineOfBusiness::class,
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);
        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'datatable' => $table
        ]);
    }
}
```

What Is sure, I reach the **console.log** in the app.js.
[image]

One of you have any idea why the post call does not fill the table even if I get a 200 html code?

[image]

@Darkbee, Thank you for this quick answer...
You totally right, I'm passing a string instead of an object into **initDatatables**

Comment: You are passing a `string` not an `object` to `initDataTables`. You would still need to convert the string with `JSON.parse(settings)`